# translating an excel formula to RStudio code (IF AND)

Tags: r, excel

I'd like to replicate this formula in R instead of in excel. It's just a simple IF AND statement, but I'm new to R and not sure how to make this work. I need a new column (The highlighted column in the image: ResponseRecoded) that gives a "left" or "right" value ONLY if the Response column has "RIGHT 1, RIGHT2, RIGHT 3, RIGHT 4" or "LEFT 1, LEFT 2, LEFT 3, LEFT 4".

[image: What I want the new column to look like (highlighted yellow)]

[image: The formula that currently works in excel]

Here is the structure of the code for the "Response" column.

```
    > MasterObjectAllocation$Response
   [1] NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        "enter"   "enter"   NA        NA        "right"   "left"    NA       
  [13] "right"   NA        NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        NA        "RIGHT 1"
  [25] "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA       
  [37] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
  [49] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
  [61] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
  [73] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
  [85] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3"
  [97] "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3"
 [109] "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
 [121] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
 [133] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
 [145] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3"
 [157] "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3"
 [169] "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 1"  "START"   "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [181] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [193] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [205] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [217] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [229] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [241] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [253] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [265] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [277] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [289] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [301] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [313] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [325] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [337] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [349] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [361] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [373] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [385] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [397] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [409] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [421] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [433] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [445] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [457] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [469] NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [481] NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
 [493] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [505] NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA       
 [517] NA        "RIGHT 1" "START"   "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
 [529] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3"
 [541] "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3"
 [553] "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
 [565] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
 [577] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA       
 [589] "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA       
 [601] "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA       
 [613] "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA       
 [625] "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        "left"   
 [637] NA        "right"   NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        "enter"   "enter"   NA       
 [649] NA        "left"    NA        "right"   NA        NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA       
 [661] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3" 
 [673] "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        NA        NA       
 [685] "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA       
 [697] "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA       
 [709] "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA       
 [721] "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "START"   "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4"
 [733] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [745] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [757] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4"
 [769] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [781] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4"
 [793] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [805] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [817] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4"
 [829] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [841] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4"
 [853] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [865] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [877] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [889] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [901] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [913] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [925] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4"
 [937] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4"
 [949] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4"
 [961] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4" NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [973] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4" 
 [985] NA        NA        "LEFT 1"  "LEFT 2"  "LEFT 3"  "LEFT 4"  NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2" "RIGHT 3" "RIGHT 4"
 [997] NA        NA        "RIGHT 1" "RIGHT 2"
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 34372 entries ]
```

Here is the output from `dput(head(MasterObjectAllocation$Response, 200))`:

```
c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "enter", "enter", NA, NA, "right", "left", 
NA, "right", NA, NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", "RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", "RIGHT 4", 
NA, NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", "RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", "RIGHT 4", NA, NA, 
NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", "LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, NA, "LEFT 1", 
"LEFT 2", "LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", 
"LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", "RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", 
"RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", "LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, 
NA, "RIGHT 1", "RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", "RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "LEFT 1", 
"LEFT 2", "LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", "RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", 
"RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", "LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, 
NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", "LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", 
"RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", "RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", 
"LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", "RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", 
"RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", "RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", "RIGHT 4", 
NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", "LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", 
"RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", "RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", 
"LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", "RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", 
"RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", "LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, 
NA, "RIGHT 1", "RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", "RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", 
"RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", "RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", 
"LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, "RIGHT 1", "RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", 
"RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", "LEFT 1", "START", "RIGHT 1", 
"RIGHT 2", "RIGHT 3", "RIGHT 4", NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", 
"LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", "LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", 
NA, NA, "LEFT 1", "LEFT 2", "LEFT 3", "LEFT 4", NA, NA, "RIGHT 1"
)
```

Comment: Could you please share a small slice of your data using `dput(head(your_data, N))`? `N` should be large enough such that we can find exactly the same structure as depicted in your picture. It would be very hard to help without knowing how the data looks like in R. Also, what is your expected output in R?

Comment: Oh man, it is such a huge data set. over 35k obs with 80 vars. I'll post the column of interest (Response).

Comment: I need a new column that will basically condense the Response column. So if they press the Right button 4 times (which would create a sequence of RIGHT 1, RIGHT 2, RIGHT 3, RIGHT4), then I want the new column to just say "right". 

If they only hit the right button 3 times (RIGHT1, RIGHT 2, RIGHT3), then I want this to just equal NA.

Comment: Hi @Tessa, thanks for the data. It seems that 200 rows should be more than enough. Could you instead post the result of this code `dput(head(MasterObjectAllocation$Response, 200))` so that we can easily copy and use it?

Comment: Hey @ ekoam, all done :) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do rolling computations using the `slider` package in R. You need to `install.packages("slider")` if you do not have it installed. Here is the code

```
MasterObjectAllocation$ResponseRecoded <- 
  sub("^([^ ]+) .*", "\\1", MasterObjectAllocation$Response) |>
  slider::slide_chr(
    \(x) if (length(x) > 3L && (all(x %in% "LEFT") || all(x %in% "RIGHT"))) x[[1L]] else NA_character_, 
    .before = 3L
  )
```

Output

```
    Response ResponseRecoded
1       <NA>            <NA>
2       <NA>            <NA>
3       <NA>            <NA>
4       <NA>            <NA>
5       <NA>            <NA>
6      enter            <NA>
7      enter            <NA>
8       <NA>            <NA>
9       <NA>            <NA>
10     right            <NA>
11      left            <NA>
12      <NA>            <NA>
13     right            <NA>
14      <NA>            <NA>
15      <NA>            <NA>
16      <NA>            <NA>
17   RIGHT 1            <NA>
18   RIGHT 2            <NA>
19   RIGHT 3            <NA>
20   RIGHT 4           RIGHT
21      <NA>            <NA>
22      <NA>            <NA>
23      <NA>            <NA>
24   RIGHT 1            <NA>
25   RIGHT 2            <NA>
26   RIGHT 3            <NA>
27   RIGHT 4           RIGHT
28      <NA>            <NA>
29      <NA>            <NA>
30      <NA>            <NA>
31    LEFT 1            <NA>
32    LEFT 2            <NA>
33    LEFT 3            <NA>
34    LEFT 4            LEFT
35      <NA>            <NA>
36      <NA>            <NA>
37      <NA>            <NA>
38    LEFT 1            <NA>
39    LEFT 2            <NA>
40    LEFT 3            <NA>
41    LEFT 4            LEFT
42      <NA>            <NA>
43      <NA>            <NA>
44      <NA>            <NA>
45      <NA>            <NA>
46    LEFT 1            <NA>
47    LEFT 2            <NA>
48    LEFT 3            <NA>
49    LEFT 4            LEFT
50      <NA>            <NA>
51      <NA>            <NA>
52   RIGHT 1            <NA>
53   RIGHT 2            <NA>
54   RIGHT 3            <NA>
55   RIGHT 4           RIGHT
56      <NA>            <NA>
57      <NA>            <NA>
58    LEFT 1            <NA>
59    LEFT 2            <NA>
60    LEFT 3            <NA>
61    LEFT 4            LEFT
62      <NA>            <NA>
63      <NA>            <NA>
64   RIGHT 1            <NA>
65   RIGHT 2            <NA>
66   RIGHT 3            <NA>
67   RIGHT 4           RIGHT
68      <NA>            <NA>
69      <NA>            <NA>
70    LEFT 1            <NA>
71    LEFT 2            <NA>
72    LEFT 3            <NA>
73    LEFT 4            LEFT
74      <NA>            <NA>
75      <NA>            <NA>
76   RIGHT 1            <NA>
77   RIGHT 2            <NA>
78   RIGHT 3            <NA>
79   RIGHT 4           RIGHT
80      <NA>            <NA>
81      <NA>            <NA>
82    LEFT 1            <NA>
83    LEFT 2            <NA>
84    LEFT 3            <NA>
85    LEFT 4            LEFT
86      <NA>            <NA>
87      <NA>            <NA>
88    LEFT 1            <NA>
89    LEFT 2            <NA>
90    LEFT 3            <NA>
91    LEFT 4            LEFT
92      <NA>            <NA>
93      <NA>            <NA>
94   RIGHT 1            <NA>
95   RIGHT 2            <NA>
96   RIGHT 3            <NA>
97   RIGHT 4           RIGHT
98      <NA>            <NA>
99      <NA>            <NA>
100   LEFT 1            <NA>
101   LEFT 2            <NA>
102   LEFT 3            <NA>
103   LEFT 4            LEFT
104     <NA>            <NA>
105     <NA>            <NA>
106  RIGHT 1            <NA>
107  RIGHT 2            <NA>
108  RIGHT 3            <NA>
109  RIGHT 4           RIGHT
110     <NA>            <NA>
111     <NA>            <NA>
112  RIGHT 1            <NA>
113  RIGHT 2            <NA>
114  RIGHT 3            <NA>
115  RIGHT 4           RIGHT
116     <NA>            <NA>
117     <NA>            <NA>
118   LEFT 1            <NA>
119   LEFT 2            <NA>
120   LEFT 3            <NA>
121   LEFT 4            LEFT
122     <NA>            <NA>
123     <NA>            <NA>
124  RIGHT 1            <NA>
125  RIGHT 2            <NA>
126  RIGHT 3            <NA>
127  RIGHT 4           RIGHT
128     <NA>            <NA>
129     <NA>            <NA>
130   LEFT 1            <NA>
131   LEFT 2            <NA>
132   LEFT 3            <NA>
133   LEFT 4            LEFT
134     <NA>            <NA>
135     <NA>            <NA>
136  RIGHT 1            <NA>
137  RIGHT 2            <NA>
138  RIGHT 3            <NA>
139  RIGHT 4           RIGHT
140     <NA>            <NA>
141     <NA>            <NA>
142   LEFT 1            <NA>
143   LEFT 2            <NA>
144   LEFT 3            <NA>
145   LEFT 4            LEFT
146     <NA>            <NA>
147     <NA>            <NA>
148  RIGHT 1            <NA>
149  RIGHT 2            <NA>
150  RIGHT 3            <NA>
151  RIGHT 4           RIGHT
152     <NA>            <NA>
153     <NA>            <NA>
154  RIGHT 1            <NA>
155  RIGHT 2            <NA>
156  RIGHT 3            <NA>
157  RIGHT 4           RIGHT
158     <NA>            <NA>
159     <NA>            <NA>
160   LEFT 1            <NA>
161   LEFT 2            <NA>
162   LEFT 3            <NA>
163   LEFT 4            LEFT
164     <NA>            <NA>
165     <NA>            <NA>
166  RIGHT 1            <NA>
167  RIGHT 2            <NA>
168  RIGHT 3            <NA>
169  RIGHT 4           RIGHT
170     <NA>            <NA>
171     <NA>            <NA>
172   LEFT 1            <NA>
173   LEFT 2            <NA>
174   LEFT 1            <NA>
175    START            <NA>
176  RIGHT 1            <NA>
177  RIGHT 2            <NA>
178  RIGHT 3            <NA>
179  RIGHT 4           RIGHT
180     <NA>            <NA>
181     <NA>            <NA>
182   LEFT 1            <NA>
183   LEFT 2            <NA>
184   LEFT 3            <NA>
185   LEFT 4            LEFT
186     <NA>            <NA>
187     <NA>            <NA>
188   LEFT 1            <NA>
189   LEFT 2            <NA>
190   LEFT 3            <NA>
191   LEFT 4            LEFT
192     <NA>            <NA>
193     <NA>            <NA>
194   LEFT 1            <NA>
195   LEFT 2            <NA>
196   LEFT 3            <NA>
197   LEFT 4            LEFT
198     <NA>            <NA>
199     <NA>            <NA>
200  RIGHT 1            <NA>
```

Comment: This is awesome - thank you!!!